# How can I change the bitcoin core version within an already installed blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I want to change the version in the corresponding
directory with `git tag` and `git checkout vx.y.z`.

But when I type `git tag` there's no output.
How can I change the version without installing the blockchain again? Clone the git repo in the already existing directory?

I also tried to fetch the git tag but this didn't work either...

Comment: you can get the new software and run it using the same blockchain dir?

Comment: Just don’t run them with the same directory at the same time.
— Did you install from the source code?

Comment: @Murch yes I did. But now, looking up the git tags, only versions until v0.11.0rc2 are shown and no further versions.

Comment: Are you perhaps pulling from your own fork of the repository?

Comment: @Murch I don't know how can I check? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145872/discussion-on-question-by-pariya-how-can-i-change-the-bitcoin-core-version-with); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: In case it’s not clear, you should be able to join the chat by clicking the link in the previous comment, so that we can walk you through figuring out what the issue is. Since there is very little information in your question so far, and it seems more of a git issue than a Bitcoin problem, that seemed more likely to get you help.